# Usage of @ in powershell

Tags: powershell

I often see the usage of @ symbol in Powershell coding. Want to ask what is it used for? Example as below

```
$DistributionPointGroups = @("London")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@()` is the array operator, which makes sure that even a single item (or zero) is returned as an array.

> THE ARRAY SUB-EXPRESSION OPERATOR
>
> The array sub-expression operator creates an array, even if it 
>       contains zero or one object.
>
> ```
> The syntax of the array operator is as follows:
>     @( ... )
>
> You can use the array operator to create an array of zero or 
> one object. 
>
>     PS C:\>$a = @("One")
>     PS C:\>$a.Count
>     1
>
>     PS C:\>$b = @()
>     PS C:\>$b.Count
>     0
> ```

Source: [about_Arrays](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847882.aspx)